# Using getopts in Bash to specify variables results in an illegal option error

Tags: bash, getopts

I was attempting to specify variables' values using getopts in Bash. But whenever trying to use flag `-l` or `-c`, I get an error: `illegal option -- l`.

```bash
DIR="./"
LENGTH=0
CHAR="a"

while getopts "hd:" arg; do
  case ${arg} in
    d)
      DIR=${OPTARG};;
    l)
      LENGTH=$OPTARG;;
    c)
      CHAR=$OPTARG;;
    h)
      echo "Flags:"
      echo "-h: display help"
      echo "-d: specify directory"
      echo "-l: specify length"
      echo "-c: specify character"
      exit 0;;
  esac
done
echo $DIR
echo $LENGTH
echo $CHAR
```

Could you please tell what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Looks like your `while getopts "hd:" arg; do` line is missing both the `l` and the `c`.  Try changing that line to `while getopts "hdlc:" arg; do`.   Also, make sure your script has a proper shebang.

Comment: Further,  you could paste your code into https://www.shellcheck.net/ and correct the issues that are identified.

Comment: I changed it to `getopts "h:d:l:c:"` and it works.

Comment: I thing that should be `getopts "hd:l:c:"`. With a colon after "h", that indicates that `-h` requires an argument (i.e. `$OPTARG`), which doesn't make any sense.